# Skip authentication for specific member action in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I'm trying to skip the authentication for a custom ActiveAdmin member action that I've created. Here's what I've been trying, but it still brings me to the login page.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foo, as: "Foos" do

  controller do
    skip_before_action :authenticate_admin_user!, only: :bar
  end

  member_action :bar, method: :get do
    # render something
  end

end
```

Versions:

- Rails: 4.1.1
- ActiveAdmin: 1.0.0.pre1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/scottwb/1851142).
2. Put the `self.filters` and `self.before_filters` methods into `controller do` block.
3. Add `binding.pry` after those methods and restart application server - this should stops on binding.
4. Type filters(:before) and you will see a list of callbacks.
5. Find the callback responsible for authentication, e.g. `authenticate_active_admin_user`.
6. Add `skip_before_filter :authenticate_active_admin_user` to `controller do` block.
7. Have a break :)